# English dates are not recognized by my German excel

Tags: excel, date, non-english

I have some data e.g.:

01-Oct-2017 00:44:40

02-Feb-2018 04:20:12

My german Excel recognizes the second date, but not the first one.
The reason is that "Feb" is also "Feb" in German, but "Oct" is "Okt".

I tried setting my language to English in the general options and the location in the "Format Cells" settings to the US.

Comment: If this is for a one-time event, try setting your `control panel` --> `Windows Regional Settings` to English.

Comment: Why is this really a problem? I mean, if you write it in "German" and then send the file to an "English" user, the dates would be changed magically to "English" and you should not care about it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried this, it does not help

Comment: Then there might be some other issue.  Are you sure you changed it in the Windows settings (NOT in the Excel settings)?

Comment: @Vityata I dont care about the format of the dates, but some cells will not get interpreted as dates.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I changed it in the Windows Settings. (and in the Excel Settings aswell)

Comment: @PascalIv - Where do you get the file from? If you get it as another Excel file, then you may ask the person sending it to format the cells as Date in their own version.

Comment: See this solution - https://superuser.com/questions/982430/converting-german-date-string-into-english-excel

Comment: @PascalIv You may also need to change your short date format to dd-MMM-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, if this is for a one-time event, try setting your control panel --> Windows Regional Settings to English.  Excel will then parse the dates correctly.

If you need a formula to do this repeatedly, you can use `INDEX(MATCH`  to convert the English to German, and then format it how you want.

The below example translates German to English, but you can adapt it easily to go the other way.

```
B1: =IFERROR(--REPLACE(A1,4,3,INDEX($E$1:$E$12,MATCH(MID(A1,4,3),$D$1:$D$12,0))),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know why, but changing my Regional Settings does not help. The formula however works perfectly for me!

Comment: @PascalIv Glad to help